# Android : In Lollipop sms intent not return to app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-5.0-lollipop

I am using this code to open SMS Intent in my Android app. But after Sending SMS it does not come back to application in lollipop device, while it is working ok in lower versions(tested on Jelly Beans).

```
String sentSMS = "xxxxxxxx"
String cellNumber = "xxxxx"
sentSMSId = generateId();
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + cellNumber));
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", sentSMS);
sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent",true);
startActivityForResult(sendIntent,1001);
```

Answer (score 0):

When i applied your code.app able to return to the activity correctly

```
 public  void Ok(View v){
        String sentSMS = "asd";
        String cellNumber = "123";

        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + cellNumber));
    sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", sentSMS);
    sendIntent.putExtra("exit_on_sent",true);
    startActivityForResult(sendIntent,1001);
}

    @Override
    public void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int requestCode, Bundle options) {
        super.startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode, options);
        if (requestCode==1001) Toast.makeText(this,"hai",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

This is what i tried so far.I run the app on a lollipop device and after send the message the control get back to our application..